# i need to give value for database from java code,for details see the code below

Tags: java, database

I need to insert value which is stored in `"name"` variable into the database. Till Now, i have tried below code ,but its not working.

`String name="Aswini";`

```
String query="INSERT INTO STUDENT"+"VALUES (1239,'name', 'IT')";
statement.executeUpdate(quer);
```

Can any one help me in this,thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking, and clearly show what you have tried.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Modify your string and then try

```
String query="INSERT INTO STUDENT"+"VALUES (1239,'"+name+"', 'IT')";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way of use db query. You should go with prepared statements.

Still you can correct this as follows.

```
String query="INSERT INTO STUDENT"+"VALUES (1239,'"+name+"', 'IT')";
```

But best way is

```
    String name="Aswini";
    Connection conn = null;
    String query="INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (1239,?, 'IT')";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String messageType = "trading";
    try {
        conn = // initialize connection
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1,name);
```

Comment: Hai Ruchira i used same way as said ,but still its gettion below error.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat sampleExa .main (sampleExa. java:62)

Comment: @tejareddy make sure your `conn` is not `null` here.

Comment: try {
         // conn = // initialize connection
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","usename","pswrd"); i have given like this,please help me still i'm not able  to get it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user:1869846:String query="INSERT INTO STUDENT"+"VALUES (?,?,?)";
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
 Connection connection = DriverManager .getConnection ("jdbc:oracle :thin:@localhost:1521:xe","Tejswini","Tejswini");                                                       PreparedStatement updateemp  =connection.prepareStatement(query);
    updateemp.setInt(1,23);
 updateemp.setString(2,"Roshan");   updateemp.setString(3, "CEO"); updateemp.executeUpdate();please help me i tried dis way but still getting error,java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Comment: @tejareddy please follow these instructions.. http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-insert-a-record/ . If you are still facing an issue contact me via skype. you can find my contact info in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert using Table like that

```
String query="INSERT INTO STUDENT"+"VALUES (1239,'"+name+"', 'IT')";
```